How to use docker exec to execute a shell script with an argument in a container?
I have a shell script on my host, which is calling another script to run inside the container. Here is a simple case that works fine:
host_script.sh
#!/bin/sh

results=$(docker exec mycontainer "./scripts/container_script.sh")
echo $results

container_script.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World"

However, now I would like to run the container script with an input argument instead. Like this:
host_script.sh
#!/bin/sh

path="/some/other/path"
results=$(docker exec mycontainer "./scripts/container_script.sh $path")
echo $results

container_script.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World"
echo $1

This time I receive the error:

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./scripts/container_script.sh /some/other/path": stat ./scripts/container_script.sh /some/other/path: no such file or directory: unknown

How can I pass in an argument to this script inside the container?
